# invoice, colour, type, count

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a table below:

```
Invoice| Colour | Type

In_001 |  Red   | D  
In_001 |  Red   | D  
In_001 | Yellow | E  
In_002 |  Red   | H
```

My desired result is to sort out any invoice which has more than
two items purchased and show the count.

See below, the desired result:

```
Invoice | Colour | Type | Count

In_001  |  Red   |  D   | 2  
In_001  | Yellow |  E   | 1
```

Remark: In_002 is not included due to the fact that, it has only one item purchased.

I tried the following command:

```
select invoice, colour, type, count(invoice) from t   
group by invoice,colour,type   
having count(invoice)>1;
```

The result is:

```
Invoice | Colour | Type | Count

In_001  |  Red   |  D   | 2
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The group by is for all the three invoice,colour and type. So the result will be like that only.
We can try the below query to achieve it:-

```
select invoice,colour,type,count(invoice) from t where invoice in
(select invoice from t group by invoice having count(invoice) >1) 
group by invoice,colour,type
```

Comment: U will have accept option for your question and up arrow near the answer will upvote